# Is it possible to clear DNS cache globally?

Tags: dns, webserver, cache

Users are complaining they are seeing the old content, which is from the old website after we switched to new server. So they are looking at completely different website practically. Many of them don't have a clue about DNS cache. Is there something we could do to invalidate cache globally, so browsers are forced to clean it, or would it help if we take the old site down? Something has to be done, users don't care and don't know about the cache.

**UPDATE:**

Switch was 3 days ago, people are still getting old site.

Comment: I suspect you would need your users to set their browser locally to not cache/remove cache on application shutdown/restart.

Comment: How long has it been since you switched?

Comment: @w3d 3 days, just updated the question.

Comment: Unless you are providing them the DNS itself you won't be able to change their DNS information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The reason behind this, is because just flushing DNS (a restart should do this) won't help if the local PC and browser cache the DNS as well.

The option is to restart your DNS and ask users to reboot. It's a little overkill, but if they don't understand DNS cache, you will be spending enormous energy on helping them clear local cache...

The best solution to ensuring that this doesn't happen in future, is lowering your TTL for the domain a few days before moving to something like 5 minutes (1 if you're confident you have low levels of DNS queries for that domain), changing it, and then upping the TTL afterwards.

Aside from that, you could also create a redirect on the website (iptables, modrewite) to point to a new IP.

Comment: Presumably you would only be able to implement the _redirect_ if you are not on a shared server?

Comment: Mod_rewrite is configurable per domain name, so this would work in a shared environment. Also, iptables could be configured to redirect based on SRC IP, which could be the internal network, thereby not affecting anyone else.

Comment: It's just that you would need to redirect to an IP address (as you suggest), rather than a domain name (since that is already cached by the client; pointing to the wrong IP). A shared server (one IP address for multiple websites) requires the domain name in order to resolve to the required website. ?

Comment: If all the domains on the shared server were configured with names, you could still use the IP as a "name" inside your virtual host configuration. But in general, this is far from ideal, so I would agree with your comment ;)

Comment: Solution was, as sysadmin said in making a "reverse proxy" on the old server back to new instance. I don't know more details :)

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to get in contact with administrators of the ~32 **million** DNS servers out on the public Internet much less get them to clear the cache on their servers without a really compelling reason, like buying them all a drink for their trouble.

Proper planning ahead of a change to drop the TTL down is best-practice.  Too late for you, but at least now you know.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few places where you can force major name servers to update there DNS record caches for your domain.

1. https://1.1.1.1/purge-cache/
2. https://dns.google/cache
3. https://cachecheck.opendns.com/

DNS is a decentralized technology where DNS Servers reach out to each other over time for updated records after they expire (records have a ttl (time to live) value, some DNS servers respect this value others do not. The idea behind the purge cache strategy, is if you are able to force a few major DNS servers to have the most current records from your name server, the records will propogate more quickly out to the rest of the internet.

Comment: Link only answer is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a litle more?

Comment: Hows that? @Toto